Web browser keeps the old JWT in cache when switching user's session
I have a problem in my Nuxt3-based website where when I log in to an user account, then log out and log in to another user account, the generated JWT isn't taken in account by my browser.
What I mean is, I store it in localStorage at login, it works fine, I can do my CRUD as expected.
But when I log out and log in to another test account, my web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) don't seem to update the JWT in their cache. So when I update something in my database, my updated_by column is filled with the id of the previous account logged in, not the current one. To solve this issue, I have to manually clear my browser's cache.
Here is the login and logout logic I'm using.
// Login function
export async function login(credentials) {
  try {
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
    const response = await fetch(`${runtimeConfig.public.auth}/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })

    if (response.status === 401) {
      throw 'Invalid credentials'
    }

    const data = await response.json()
    if (data.token) {
      localStorage.setItem('jwt', data.token)
      await navigateTo('/dashboard')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}

// Logout function
export async function logout() {
  try {
    await localStorage.removeItem('jwt')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

And the block where the logout function is being called in a component:
async function logOut() {
  await logout()
  await navigateTo('/login')
}

<button @click="logOut()" class="menu_item">Disconnect</button>

I tried adding a localStorage.clear(), but I didn't try to clear the cache into the function, I've read that this is not a good practice.
What I expect to do is to not having to manually clear my browser's cache every time i switch users account for it to aknowledge that the JWT data has changed.

Turns out I had to add a window.location.reload() into both my login and logout functions to make it work properly. It wasn't a cache issue at all.
